# Alter MySQL DB column value in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB with a column that sometimes has a value of "-1", how can I change that to "0" during the SELECT without doing a foreach loop on the result. Basically I want the 'display' value to be 0 if the DB value is -1. If the DB value is anything else then it should be displayed without modification.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend on App.net chimed in with:

```
SELECT IF(mycol=-1, 0, mycol)
```

Which seems to work a treat. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `case` syntax:

```
select case 
       when col = -1 then 0
       else col
       end case
from Tab
```

or

```
  select case col
           when -1 then 0
           else col
           end case
    from Tab
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) are more informations.

or `if construct`

```
select if(col=-1,0,col)
from Tab
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) are more informations.

Comment: I think IF() statement is more simple but that is only my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Or "IF" scalar function for shorter syntax

```
SELECT IF (col = -1, 0, col)
FROM Tab
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 0):

Another option then case statement is IF function as below given

```
//IF(expr,if_true_expr,if_false_expr)
SELECT IF(column = -1, 0, column) AS state FROM table
```